# Android application terminates after activity.finish() in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a specific render for the page FacebookFriends that is called like this:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new FacebookFriends());
```

and then my render for android of that page

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PinBuster.FacebookFriends), typeof(PinBuster.Droid.FacebookFriends))]
```

when I call :

```
var activity = this.Context as Activity;
activity.Finish();
```

the application shuts down. Does anyone know why? shouldn't it go back to the previous page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have only one activity in Xamarin.Android project. So whenever you are finishing that activity your application was terminating.

Because of only one activity in your application, it was terminating your application.

Comment: What should I do then? Can I access the Navigation from the ContentPage and do PopAsync() on the Android file? @Venkata

Comment: Yes. Write Custom Renderer for your Content Page and then do PopAsync() on ContentPage from Android.

Comment: Technically you can have as many activities as you want in a Xamarin.Android project.  The Xamarin Forms library you are using is the one imposing the single activity on you.

Comment: How can I do a PopAsync in the Android activity? Do I have access to the Navigation? @Venkata

Comment: By Using instance of App.cs you can access the methods in the App.cs from Android project. Create a method in App.cs for PopAsync() and call that method from Android.